# trying to store values from Firebase to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am accessing firebase database and getting the values and storing in a property. When i try to access the property outside the method I am getting "NULL". can anyone help me with this I am new to obj c programming

```
-(void)buildUsersInDatabase {
     FIRDatabaseReference *referenceToDatabase = [[FIRDatabase database]reference];
    [[referenceToDatabase child:@"Users"]observeEventType: FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        self.dict = @{@"Name": snapshot.value[@"Name"],
                               @"Email":snapshot.value[@"Email"]};

    }];
}
```

Comment: Where are you accessing this dictionary. Paste more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `-[FIRDatabaseReference observeEventType:withBlock:]` is asynchronous; the code insisde the block will be executed when the observed event occurs.

In contrast, your method `-buildUsersInDatabase` just registers the block and exits right away; `self.dict` will be `nil` until the observed event happens and the pased block is actually executed.

Source: [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I modified my code to return values when the execution completes and was able to print the values.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit incomplete. 
try using NSMutableDictionary

```
self.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[self.dict setObject:snapshot.value[@"Name"] forKey:@"Name"];
[self.dict setObject:snapshot.value[@"Email"] forKey:@"Email"];
```

may be this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For using the child added observer you need to do add all keys one by one as it will give you trigger on each child added

**Note** This will not inform you about the change of value of any child for that you need to add a another observer for valueChanged using *FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged*

```
-(void)buildUsersInDatabase {
    FIRDatabaseReference *referenceToDatabase = [[FIRDatabase database]reference];
    [[referenceToDatabase child:@"Users"]observeEventType: FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        if (!self.dict){
            self.dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        }
        [self.dict setObject:snapshot.value forKey:snapshot.key];

    }];
}
```

If you wish you can also use the value event, which will give you whole dictionary at that child whenever a value changes...

```
-(void)buildUsersInDatabase {
    FIRDatabaseReference *referenceToDatabase = [[FIRDatabase database]reference];
    [[referenceToDatabase child:@"Users"]observeEventType: FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        if (!self.dict){
            self.dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        }
        self.dict = snapshot.value;
    }];
}
```